# Inner product is a function from…to…?

Tags: linear-algebra

Example, if $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^2$, then the inner (dot) product defined by 
$$f(v,w) = \left< v,w \right>$$

is bilinear, so is $f$ a function from $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ or just $\mathbb{R}^2$? I thought that $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R}^4$? The reason I conjectured the cartesian product is because it takes in two vectors.

My brain is farting tonight, that's why I am asking such a basic question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have every right to "brain-fart" here; this stuff is confusing.

Yes, you are correct in writing that $f$ is a function from $\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$, since we are taking two parameters, each of which is (a vector) in $\Bbb R^2$.

Now, if we were to break this down further, we would note that $\Bbb R^2 = \Bbb R \times \Bbb R$, so that we have
$$
\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R^2 = (\Bbb R \times \Bbb R) \times (\Bbb R \times \Bbb R)
$$
and it is natural to identify this with 
$$
\Bbb R^4 = \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \times \Bbb R
$$
However, the Cartesian product is not "associative" in this way, and so these to sets are considered distinct.  One consists of pairs of the form $((x_1,x_2),(x_3,x_4))$, and the other consists of quadruples of the form $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$. Yes, there is a natural connection between them, but they are not quite "identical".

Comment: I am probably repeating what you just said, but you are basically saying that $$\Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R^2 = (\Bbb R \times \Bbb R) \times (\Bbb R \times \Bbb R) \neq \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \times \Bbb R = \Bbb R^4 ?$$

Comment: That is exactly right.  They're structurally similar (isomorphic, homeomorphic, isometric, etc.), but different "entities".

Comment: And of course, both of these are similar but not identical to $\Bbb R^{2 \times 2}$.

Comment: Let's not go there…lol

Comment: Your final paragraph, possibly it should say 'the other consists of quadruples' or something like that?

Comment: @gj255 ...yes, I suppose four objects is too many for a pair.

Answer (score 2):

An inner product by definition is a function from $ V \times V \to \Bbb F $ where $F$ is the field over which $V$ is defined.

Hence the function $f$ is a function from $ \Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R $.

The equation $ \Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R^2 = \Bbb R^4 $ does not make any sense. The notation $ \Bbb R^2 \times \Bbb R^2 $ denotes the set of all duples $ [(x, y), (x', y')] $ where $ (x, y), (x', y') \in \Bbb R^2 $ that is, $x, y, x', y' \in \Bbb R$

Comment: "does not make any sense", I know…that's why I am saying my brain is being stupid tonight...

Comment: Hope the brain is a teensy bit clearer now?

Comment: It is, thanks to you. =)

Comment: Glad to help.. .

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is a function from $\mathbb R^2 \times \mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$.